# How do i look up an email address form its header?

Tags: php, security, email

I'm currently using the following function to check valid email provider-

```
function chkEmailProvider($hn, $rt = ''){
    if( $rt == '' ) $rt = "MX";
    exec("nslookup -type=$rt $hn", $result);
    foreach ($result as $line) {
        if(eregi("^$hn",$line)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But don't know how to get email sender details from email header. Could you please help me? How to do that?

Again is that possible to check the availability of an email address?

Looking forward to your valuable solutions..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide us with what seems to be the problem. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. My problem is not the "error". Actually I need to know "how to get email sender details from email header?"
And "is that possible to check the availability of an email address?"

Comment: Is it something like http://www.mailboxvalidator.com?

Comment: Quite same. I'm looking for these three answer, 1. Checking the email server validity (Its working with the above chkEmailProvider() function). 2. Checking email address availability (email exist or not) and 3. Get email sender details from email header. You can check this following links: "http://www.ip-tracker.org/checker/email-lookup.php" and "ip-tracker.org/find/email-finder.php". I need exactly the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many shared hosting environments disable `exec`. Consdier using [checkdnsrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) instead

```
function chkEmailProvider($hn, $rt = ''){
    if( $rt == '' ) $rt = "MX";
    return checkdnsrr($hn, $rt);
}
```

As to checking if the email itself is valid... that's difficult without actually sending an email to the server and checking for a bounce (which might earn you a spot on a spam list)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But this is not my problem. Actually I need to know:
1. "how to get email sender details from email header?"
2. "is that possible to check the availability of an email address?"

Comment: It depends. You don't have to send email with a valid `from` address. But you can always parse it out. The function above will at least ensure that they have a valid domain and MX records required for sending email.

Comment: I think I'm unable to make my point clear. If possible, please have a look. I need this actions, Email Look Up "http://www.ip-tracker.org/checker/email-lookup.php" and Email finder "http://www.ip-tracker.org/find/email-finder.php"
Thanks.